# How R write a Macro like SAS

Tags: r, macros, rodbc

I have a really long sqlquery like this, and need to run a few times by only changing the date. I am good at SAS but quite new to R, so I am struggling to write something similar to SAS.

```
df <- sqlQuery(datamart, paste0("Select xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx from xxxxx
where date = '28Feb2018'"), as.is=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Can you share some experience please?

Thank you!

---

edited on 6/5/2018:

I edited the code according to the answers below and I still have some trouble in running the code correctly.
currently my code become:

```
safeqry <- function(date_string)
{require(RODBCext)
qry_string <- paste0("DELETE FROM [T_SPP] WHERE [BkDt]<=#?","#")
  parms <- data.frame(date_string, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  sqlExecute(access, qry_string, parms, fetch=TRUE)}
safeqry('2016-04-30')
```

error is :

> 42000 -3100 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in date in query expression '[BkDt]<=#Pa_RaM000'.
>   [RODBCext] Error: SQLExecute failed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In sqlExecute(access, qry_string, parms, fetch = TRUE) :

the other code is

```
query_delete = function (table, date_col, date) {
paste0('DELETE FROM [',table,'] WHERE [',date_col,']<=#',date, '#')}
sqlQuery(access, query_delete("T_SPP", "BkDt", "2018-04-30"),as.is = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

error is

> [1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'DELETE FROM [T_SPP] WHERE [BkDt]<=#2018-04-30#'"

Comment: You can use a for loop. `for (date in dates) {...}` and then use `paste0` to paste `date` into your SQL.

Comment: C_Mu, does one of the answers resolve your question?

Comment: i finally figure out how to do it, and these answers gave me lots of hints, here is the final code works. thank you all for helping me here.

Comment: query_string = function(table, date_col_name, date) {
  x=paste0('Delete From ', table, ' Where ', date_col_name, "<=#", date, "#")
}
q_delete = function(table, date_col_name, date) {
  q1=query_string(table, date_col_name, date)
  sqlQuery(access,q1)
  rm(q1)
}

Answer (score 5):

The R equivalent to a SAS macro is a function. So you write a function that takes the date as a parameter, and then pass the date to the query.

The simplest way to do it is via string manipulation:

```
qry <- function(date_string)
{
    qry_string <- paste0("select xxxxx from yyy where date = '", date_string, "'")
    sqlQuery(datamart, qry_string, as.is=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

HOWEVER, this is generally unsafe because people can pass malicious strings to your function, causing it to do [Bad Things.](https://xkcd.com/327/) Instead, consider using the [RODBCext package](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RODBCext) to run parameterized queries rather than messing with strings:

```
safeqry <- function(date_string)
{
    require(RODBCext)
    qry_string <- paste0("select xxxxx from yyy where date = ?")
    parms <- data.frame(date_string, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    sqlExecute(datamart, qry_string, parms, fetch=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: This would be my preferred method. In addition to circumventing the SQL Injection attack, `sqlExecute` will manage the repetitions for you.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method looks something like this:

```
macro1 <- function(dt) {
  qry <- paste0("select xxxxxxxxxx from xxxx where date='", dt, "'")
  sqlQuery(datamart, qry, as.is=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

But there are a couple of things wrong with it:

- it assumes the connection object `datamart` is available in the parent (and/or global) environment and is valid; if you are testing with different connections, I guarantee this will bite you in ways you do not expect; and
- it is very prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (comic: [xkcd 327](https://xkcd.com/327/))
- if your argument is empty or length 2 or more, it may not do what you want

A slightly more robust function is something like:

```
macro2 <- function(dt, con) {
  if (length(dt) == 0L) {
    stop("'dt' is not length 1")
  } else if (length(dt) > 1L) {
    warning("'dt' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")
    dt <- dt[[1L]]
  }
  qry <- sprintf("select xxxxxxxxxx from xxxx where date='%s'", sQuote(dt))
  sqlQuery(con, qry, as.is=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

though a better solution would use variable binding ("parameterized queries"), which is unique to each database-type. As Hong Ooi suggested, `RODBCext` provides this for `RODBC` connections, but you'll need something more database-specific otherwise.

If you want to be a little lazy and feel safe that the connection will always be in the global, you might be tempted to do something like:

```
macro2 <- function(dt, con=datamart) ...
```

which will work, but I still guard against it. Experience shows that explicit is often much safer and easier to troubleshoot.

From here, a loop can be used, whether a `for` loop as JasonAizkalns suggested, or, perhaps something like:

```
answers <- lapply(vector_of_dates, macro2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but since you said you are new to `R`, this might be a natural approach. First, create function which allows you to change the `select_cols`, `tbl`, and `date` and returns a string:

```
make_query <- function(select_cols, tbl, date) {
  paste0("SELECT ", select_cols, " FROM ", tbl, " WHERE date = '", date, "';")
}

make_query("*", "my_table", "28Feb2018")
[1] "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date = '28Feb2018';"
make_query("*", "different_table", "28Feb2018")
[1] "SELECT * FROM different_table WHERE date = '28Feb2018';"
```

Then you can create a vector of dates to loop through:

```
various_dates <- c("28Feb2018", "01Mar2018", "02Mar2018")

for (date in seq_along(various_dates)) {
  make_query("*", "my_table", various_dates[date])
}
```

Of course, you can modify the body of the loop to use your `sqlQuery` function:

```
for (date in seq_along(various_dates)) {
  sqlQuery(datamart, make_query("*", "my_table", various_dates[date]), 
           as.is = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

And since it looks like you want to save the results, you can pre-allocate an empty list the same length as the number of dates and save those results:

```
df <- vector("list", length(various_dates))
for (date in seq_along(various_dates)) {
  df[[date]] <- sqlQuery(datamart, make_query("*", "my_table", various_dates[date]), 
           as.is = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: First argument to `sqlQuery` appears to be a connection object or similar, not the query string.